# What is the adjective for each of "upheaval" and "debacle"?

Tags: adjectives

I know some words have their own adjective, and some can be constructed by adding the suffixes like "some", "ic", etc. But how can we mint a neologism, i.e. an adjective, for each of "**upheaval**" and "**debacle**"?

I don't desire to exercise its synonym, namely cataclysmic, devastating, etc.

Comment: Not these words.

Comment: "Upheaval" is related to the verb "upheave", so you could use the past participle as an adjective "upheaved". "Debacle" is a noun, so no such option is available. If you're wanting to "mint neologisms", you can do whatever you want, but likely no one else will adopt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no adjectives derived from either of the words you mention - "upheaval" and "debacle" - and we don't just usually "mint" new words.

However, it is common to make *compound adjectives* from a noun and a verb which might serve your purpose.

For example, you mentioned the suffix *-some*, one example of which is the adjective "*fearsome*", meaning "frightening". We might instead use the compound adjective "*fear-inducing*". I found examples of this in scholarly articles [here](https://www.verywellmind.com/the-psychology-of-fear-2671696) and [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/nn.2474). Another example is the adjective "*carcinogenic*" - we might instead say "*cancer-causing*". Again, you'll find plenty of examples of this used in credible sources.

So, you could describe something as being "*upheaval-inducing*" or "*debacle-causing*", and while they may not be common expressions they are certainly valid and would be understood.

Comment: SUPERB!, What a wonderful and exhaustive answer and hint. I have not looked at this issue from your lense and angle. Moreover,  Jack O'Flaherty put forward a worthwhile comment about "upheaval"